# How to apply custom subtotal on our woocommerce and make affect cart total

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, subtotal

I'm used to working with wordpress and of course woocommerce for ecommerce sites,
So, for the past week, I have been facing a problem which is :
there is a category of products which, once added to the cart, should lead to a precise calculation in order to give the total. So, on each product and according to the quantity of the product, we do a calculation in order to find the subtotal. I made the formula, I manage to do the calculation from the price and the quantity but I can't apply it to the subtotal and the total cart. That why I need your help. Thanks in advance,
Take a look of what I've tried to implement. See my code in the on the next line

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'action_before_cart');
function action_before_cart() {
    
    $categories   = ['circonscription'];
    
    $has_category = false;

    // Loop cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        
        $_product =  wc_get_product( $cart_item['data']->get_id() ); 
        
        //The category exist
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $has_category = true;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
    // What next when there are product in cart that are from that category?
    if ( $has_category ) { 

        /* Display Cart Items Content  */ 
        
        $_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        
        $_coefficient = ($_quantity/2) + 0.5;
        
        $_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
        
        $subtotal = round($_price * $_coefficient);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to change the subtotal and the total? or the price per line item (product) that belongs to that category? on which the subtotal and the total price would automatically change

Comment: Ok, Thank you, What I want is, product of some category add to the cart, the product have the price, now, what will happen, according to the product quantity, I make a calculation base on the formula and return it as subtotal.